# Need help for easy developpement jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for my english, i am limited. I speak just little english and use google traduction.

I have a problem with jQuery developpement. 
The project idea is to create a form dynamically.
So the HTML is as compound thereof:

```js
// On attend que le DOM Soit chargé
$(document).ready(function() { // équivalent de $(function() {}); 
 // au clic bouton Label
 $( "button:first" ).on( "click", function() {
  // On Crée les nouveaux éléments
  $('<hr/>').appendTo('#button');
  $('<span>Nom du label : </span>').appendTo('#button');
  $('<input type="text" id="label">').appendTo('#button');
  $('<button id="labelValidation">ok</button>').appendTo('#button');
  // au clic sur le bouton ok
  $('button#labelValidation').on("click", function() {
   var inputLabel = $(':text[id="label"]').val();
   $('<span>'+inputLabel+'</span>').appendTo('#gaucheForm');
  });
   /* $('hr').hide();
   $('span').hide();
   $('input').hide();
   $('#labelValidation').hide(); */
  
 });

 // au clic bouton zone de texte
 $( "button:nth-child(2)" ).on( "click", function() {
  // On Crée les nouveaux éléments
  $('<hr/>').appendTo('#button');
  $('<span>id de la zone de texte : </span>').appendTo('#button');
  $('<input type="text" id="texte">').appendTo('#button');
  $('<button id="idValidation">ok</button>').appendTo('#button');
  // au clic sur le bouton ok
  $('button#idValidation').on("click", function() {
   var inputTexte = $(':text[id="texte"]').val();
   $('<input type="texte" id='+inputTexte+'>').appendTo('#gaucheForm');
  });
 });

 // au clic bouton Label
 $( "button:nth-child(3)" ).on( "click", function() {
  // On Crée les nouveaux éléments
  $('<hr/>').appendTo('#button');
  $('<span>Texte du bouton : </span>').appendTo('#button');
  $('<input type="text" id="bouton">').appendTo('#button');
  $('<button id="btnValidation">ok</button>').appendTo('#button');
  // au clic sur le bouton ok
  $('button#btnValidation').on("click", function() {
   var inputBouton = $(':text[id="bouton"]').val();
   $('<button>'+inputBouton+'</button>').appendTo('#gaucheForm');
  });
 });

});
```

```css
html,body{
 height: 100%;
}
body {
 margin: 0;
}
#gauche {
 float: left;
 width:50%;
 min-height: 100%;
 background-color: #6CC9B2;
}
#droite {
 background-color: #57B8C9;
 min-height: 100%;
 padding : 10px;
 float: right;
 width: 45%;
}
button{
 background-color: #218D8D;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: white;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 min-width: 60px; 
}
button:hover{
 background-color: #125C5C;
}
input{
 margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}
span{
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Générateur de formulaire</title>
 <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!--css-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
 <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
 <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
     <h1>Votre formulaire</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="gauche">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12" id="gaucheForm">
          
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="droite">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
       <h3>Utilisez ces boutons pour créer votre formulaire</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12" id="button">
       <button>Label</button>
       <button>Zone de texte</button>
       <button>Bouton</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="script/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- script -->
    <script src="script/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is this:

I do not send the contents of an input in the left div and delete items created dynamically just before (hr, span, input, button).
I can either inserrer content, or delete items.
Thanks for your help

edit :

The solution is :

```
// au clic bouton Label
$( "button:first" ).on( "click", function() {
    // On Crée les nouveaux éléments
    $('<div id="creation">').appendTo('#button');
    $('<hr/>').appendTo('#creation');
    $('<span>Nom du label : </span>').appendTo('#creation');
    $('<input type="text" id="label">').appendTo('#creation');
    $('<button id="labelValidation">ok</button>').appendTo('#creation');
    // au clic sur le bouton ok
    $('button#labelValidation').on("click", function() {
        var inputLabel = $(':text[id="label"]').val();
        $('<span>'+inputLabel+'</span>').appendTo('#gaucheForm');
        $("#creation").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: You appear to be creating elements with the same ID each time the button is clicked. This will invariably cause problems.

Comment: The ID change all time. I use just one ID all time for appentTo . For element created i change all time ID